# NameError: name 'wait' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I was wondering if someone can help me out. I'm attempting to make a stand alone program for web scraping and everything appears to be working except the wait command. Running the code in a source editor makes it work perfectly but when I make the stand alone it errors out and doesn't understand the code.

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name('AppBody')))   

EC = Expected Conditions
```

Whenever I run it as a stand alone though I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stand_Alone_CAS_Automation", line 57, in <module>
NameError: name 'wait' is not defined
[17344] Failed to execute script Stand_Alone_CAS_Automation
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: So what is your `wait`? Show us how you define it

Comment: The way you stated the question, a correct answer would be: "You need to define wait as follows: `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`", but I guess we are missing details here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
NameError: name 'wait' is not defined
```

...implies that the variable **wait** which you have used in your code block was not defined.

### Solution

Either you need to define the variable `wait` as an instance of *WebDriverWait* or you can induce *WebDriverWait* as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"AppBody")))
```